# I need to add variable value in custom code of SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

```
Public Function SetVariableValue(val as Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.Variable, newval As Integer) as Integer

val.Value = val.Value + newval

Return Val.Value

End Function
```

Comment: Im facing error as There is an error on line 2 of custom code: [BC30526] Property 'Value' is 'ReadOnly'.

Comment: Check this if it helps https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/selvar/2012/02/03/modifying-report-variables-in-reporting-service-2008-r2/